# Django / Python, Using Radio Button for boolean field in Modelform?

Tags: python, django, forms, radio-button, django-forms

I'm trying to use a radio button in my modelform but its just outputting nothing when I do an override this way (it just prints the label in my form, not the radio buttosn, if I don't do the override it does a standard checkbox)

My modelfield is defined as:

```
Class Mymodelname (models.Model):
    fieldname = models.BooleanField(max_length=1, verbose_name='ECG')
```

My modelform is defined as such:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from web1.myappname.models import Mymodelname

class createdbentry(forms.ModelForm):

    choices = ( (1,'Yes'),
                (0,'No'),
              )

    fieldname = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect
            (choices=choices))
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice on what I'm doing wrong.. thanks

```
class Meta:
    model = Mymodelname
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
class createdbentry(forms.ModelForm):

    choices = ( (1,'Yes'),
                (0,'No'),
              )

    class Meta:
        model = Mymodelname

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(createdbentry, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        BinaryFieldsList = ['FirstFieldName', 'SecondFieldName', 'ThirdFieldName']
        for field in BinaryFieldsList:
            self.fields[field].widget = forms.RadioSelect(choices=choices)
```

Comment: @Rick sorry, extra ) on last line, edited out now.

Comment: No problem rick. Remember to call super before you modify anything.

Comment: Also, whilst I'm at it, MarkItUp for Django is a great utility to use via this mechanism to let users format their own text fields.

Comment: thanks, I'm still fairly new to python so I'm struggling a bit with this, I'm wondering how I could wrap this in a for loop so that I could do this for each field from a list of fields, the way I tried doing this it just applied the radio button to the last field.. also, thanks will check out markitup

Comment: I've edited it so that you iterate over a list of field names and edit that field each time. Have fun!

Comment: @Ninefingers, thanks I really appreciate all your help in this